# Magnify content behind a div which is draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to know how could i zoom in the contents behind the div which is an orange box, and the box is draggable. Wherever the box is dragged the content behind it should be magnified. How can this be done?
I have tried multiple things and i could only magnify images but not texts and other elements on page.Even tried scale property of css but it only scales the box not the contents behind it.

```css
 .my-left-bar {
            left: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            background:#faa21b;
            height: 100%;
            
        }

        .my-top-bar {
            top: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            background:#faa21b;
           
        }

        .my-right-bar {
            right: 10px;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            background: #faa21b;
          
        }

        .my-bottom-bar {
            bottom: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            background: #faa21b;
           
        }

        #zoom-outer-layer {
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            border: 12px solid #faa21b;
            width: 170px;
            height: 170px;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: move;
            position: absolute;

        }
        
     
        #zoom-inner-layer {
            position: relative;
           border: 1px solid gray;
           
            height: 170px;
            width: 170px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(function () {
            $("#zoom-outer-layer").draggable();
        });

</script>
<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
                a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
                remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
                Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
                of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
              
            <div id="zoom-outer-layer" >
                <div class="my-left-bar"></div>
                <div class="my-right-bar"></div>
                <div class="my-top-bar"></div>
                <div class="my-bottom-bar"></div>
                <div id="zoom-inner-layer">
        
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: CSS scale might be worth a look at, ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use to calculate the font size, line height, and the line breaks to determine what text is under I imagine this is doable with JavaScript if anyone could help with the algorithm. Then in the box you would render the same text under the box but in a larger font.

Another option that might work for you is rendering the text to a canvas element and using a 'magnifier' on that, I threw together a quick example using the canvas approach.

```js
const wrapText = (context, text, x, y, width, lineHeight) => {
  var words = text.trim().split(' ');
  var line = '';

  for (let word of words) {
    if (context.measureText(line + word + ' ').width > width) {
      context.fillText(line, x, y);
      line = word + ' ';
      y += lineHeight;
    } else {
      line = line + word + ' ';
    }
  }
  context.fillText(line, x, y);
}

const log = msg => {
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = `${msg}<br>`
};
(() => {
  const main = document.querySelectorAll("canvas")[0];
  const zoom = document.querySelectorAll("canvas")[1];
  const ctx = main.getContext("2d")
  const zoomCtx = zoom.getContext("2d");

  ctx.font = "20px Arial";
  wrapText(ctx, document.querySelector('p').textContent, 20, 20, main.width, 24);
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
    zoomCtx.fillStyle = "white";
    zoomCtx.fillRect(0, 0, zoom.width, zoom.height);
    const x = e.x - main.offsetLeft;
    const y = e.y - main.offsetTop;
    log(`X: ${x}, Y: ${y}`);
    zoomCtx.drawImage(main, x - zoom.width / 3, y - zoom.height / 3, zoom.width / 2, zoom.height / 2, 0, 0, zoom.width, zoom.height);
    zoom.style.top = e.pageY - (zoom.height / 2) + "px"
    zoom.style.left = e.pageX - (zoom.width / 2) + "px"
  });
})();
```

```html
<p style="display: none">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<canvas width="500" height="300" style="margin-left: 150px;"></canvas>
<canvas width="150" height="100" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; border: 1px solid black"></canvas>

<div style="margin-top: 20px; overflow: scroll; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">

</div>
```

Comment: thank you for this it really helped ,but i actually wanted to know how can i build a magnifier same as you have built using the above code for the whole page irrespective of images,buttons anything on that page. Wherever the <div> which magnifies goes,it should magnify everything present inside its vicinity.